# Line Detection and Distance Measurement in Binary Images using R

Tags: r, image-processing, line, detection, hough-transform

I would really-really appreciate any (theoretical or/and practical) guidance how I could detect, count the number of lines (normally 2 or maybe 1) on a binary image and measure the shortest distance between them. The lines are products of previous processing (rgb->grey->canny edge->cropping->dilation). I am currently trying to use R's imager package but I can think of alternatives like Matlab or Scilab.

Many-many thanks,

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6YH1.jpg)
[task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpjDv.jpg)

Comment: Do you have the equations of the lines? Or just an image which contains them? Could there be more than two lines?

Comment: Thanks- I only have the image- no equation. This image was derived from an RGB and these two lines represent the edges of a disk-like object. There can only be two edges or one (in which case I don't need to measure anything, faulty image).Many thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using Hough  Transform? It is a quite common algorithm for detecting straight lines in binary images. I think it is available in [PET package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PET/PET.pdf). Alternatively, I would also suggest using OpenCV.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to use Hough transform- very effectively detects these lines but I am struggling to: (1) count the number of lines and (2) measure the shortest distance between them mainly due to not understanding PET's Hough description.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following method...

### Step1

Start at top-left, or elsewhere, and proceed around the edge (either way) till you find a white pixel that intersects the edge. I went down the left side and found the one at 0,167.

### Step 2

Flood fill with black starting at that pixel. This will remove lower left line completely and leave the just the upper right line. If you check the mean brightness of the image at this point and it is zero, you only have one line and you stop.

### Step 3

Use a Euclidean distance morphology to calculate the distance from white pixels. I do it with ImageMagick here at the command line but you can do it in OpenCV, Matlab, or R, I presume.

```
convert lines.jpg -threshold 50% -negate -morphology Distance euclidean:4  euclidean.png
```

[image]

### Step 4

Now proceed along the line at bottom left (which you temporarily removed earlier) and find the darkest pixel on that line. That is the one that is closest to the top-left line and its brightness is the distance.